# ¿Como hacer un buscador interno con el metodo GET?

Tags: php, get, buscador

Necesito que por favor me muestren un ejemplo simple de buscador interno. Pero en serio un ejemplo muy sencillo, digamos minimalista, solo para saber los principios basicos al construir un buscador..Estoy intentandolo con el metodo GET, como hace google, pero no me sale..antes estaba intentando con java script pero creo que no se puede recoger el GET.

```
    <form action="" method="GET">
      <input type="text" name="sea" />
      <input type="submit" value="search" />
    </form>

    <?php
      if ( $_GET["name"] == "lalo" ) {
        echo '<a href="http://localhost/PHP%20Y%20SQL/practice/practica.php"></a>';
      }
?>
```

Aclaro que no quiero hacer el buscador con base de datos. No lo veo necesario. Es solo para buscar internamente. Ademas no quiero complicarme.
Preguntas:
¿Es indispensable la super global GET, o se puede hacer sin ella?
Supongo que no es necesaria la seguridad informatica para este caso que quiero hacer un buscador sin base de datos ¿no?

Comment: sobre qué se haría la búsqueda? un array? un texto/string?

Comment: Sobre los articulos de la pagina. Digamos que es una pagina de politica. Y alguien quiere buscar mas informacion sobre, por decir Trump, entonces en el buscador pone trump y le salen todos los links que hay en la pagina con la palabra "trump"

Comment: si es como el CTRL+F podes implementarlo con javascript, si no molesta que se recargue la página habría que ver si existe el $_GET y con eso ponerle los `<span>textobuscado</span` para resaltar las palabras al imprimir el texto

Comment: no entiendo. Por favor si pudieras hacer un ejemplo pequeño.